# Find the name of a "New <File Type>" in C#

Tags: c#, server, get, filenames

I'm making a program to automaticly move every file in a specific folder to my server, but I don't want my program to move "New files". But the problem is that the name of the file depends of the language of the coomputer and the type of file (For example: "New Text File" in english and "Nouveau Document Texte" in french) :/ Do anyone know if there is a way I could get this name in C# ?

**EDIT:**
Here is my current code:

```
foreach (String file in Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\sendToBackup\"))
{
    extension = Path.GetExtension(file);
    fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file);
    newF = @"Z:\Backups\" + fileName;
    if (!File.Exists(newF + extension))
    {
        File.Move(file, newF + extension);
    }
    else
    {
        File.Move(file, newF + $" ({count})" + extension);
    }
}
```

Thanks :)

Comment: can you show your code what have you tried? did you try to use .resx file. You can create a resource file for english, french and all other languages

Comment: I edited my question with the code :)

Comment: @ISHIDA resource file not going to help to find what explorer uses as prefix for new files/folders. (I seriously doubt this information is exposed so)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Sorry, I shouldn't have suggested that. There is no reason to create a resource file like you said.

Comment: `File.Exists(newF + newF + extension)` This condition will never be true due to the value of `newF` and valid path rules.

Comment: Yes, sorry, it's a typo, just corrected it now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Naming new files based on localization and culture settings is a feature of operating systems (MS Windows in your case), not a feature of programming Platforms (MS .Net) or programming languages (like C# and others).
I think you can not find the solution in .Net & C#.
In my opinion one feasible option is to find the meaning of "New Text File" in about 10 most probable languages you think your clients are using on their computers. Put these 10 lines in an enum or list and iterate them when you need to check for new file names.